# What data types can you use with a template?

Tags: c++, templates

I noticed something interesting when templates are used (and I'm still learning c++, so hopefully I haven't botched this sample code):

```
template <class T>
T Pyramid<T>::getValue(int row, int col) {
    return data[triangleNum[row] + col];
}
```

Why do we manually specify the `T` argument (as it is named in this function) as a `class`? Isn't it obvious `T` is going to be a class, or does this mean we can allow other data types to be used in the template?

So, if we were to re-create the array from scratch, could we do something like this, and if so, what data types are allowed, and what are the restrictions for this?

```
# template <class T, int length>
CustomArray<float, 365> dailyIncome;
```

Comment: @user657267 It's related, as now I know `typename` is another possible value, but still does not answer the question about other data types, such as in my example, `int`.

Comment: The answer is that `class` doesn't mean `class` in this context, it was simply repurposed for templates (before the `typename` keyword was introduced).

Comment: IQAndreas: You might want to look at `std::array` for an example in the standard not too far off from your `CustomArray`

Answer (score 0):

There are, broadly, two categories of template parameters.

1. `template<typename T>` (This is more general than marking parameter `T` as a `class` or `struct` or `union`, as it can also include primitive types like `int`, `bool`, etc.)
2. Integral constants, i.e. `template<int i>`. For instance the following construction is useful in some TMP techniques.

:

```
template<int k> struct Rank : Rank<k-1> {};
template<> struct Rank<0> {};
```

This template generates a hierarchy of `Rank` types which each inherit from one another, i.e. `Rank<0>` is a superclass of `Rank<1>` is a superclass of `Rank<2>` ...

Integral constants can be broadly construed to include `char`, and also pointers like `int *` or even a pointer to some struct. You can for instance template a class against a pointer to some fixed (static storage duration) instance of a struct of some type in memory somewhere, this can be useful.

You cannot template against anything with a ctor or dtor (when would they run?). You cannot template against a `const char *` string literal -- if you attempted to instantiate a type `my_type<"foo">` you would never be able to refer to that type again, because when you typed `my_type<"foo">` later you would get a different string literal `"foo"` and therefore a different pointer and a different type. (You can however template against a particular string *with static storage duration*.) You also cannot template against float either, because you might expect things like `my_type<2.0/3>` and `my_type<6.0/9>` to always give you the same type, and then get a rude surprise caused by floating point rounding.

You can also template against function pointers, that's sometimes really useful also.

Pointer-to-member-function templating is also possible, I've used that in the past when making some code that binds C++ classes to lua.

Here's the actual text of C++11 standard (14.1.4)

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> (4.1) — integral or enumeration type,
>
> (4.2) — pointer to object or pointer to function,
>
> (4.3) — lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
>
> (4.4) — pointer to member,
>
> (4.5) — std::nullptr_t.
>
> [ Note: Other types are disallowed either explicitly below or implicitly by the rules governing the form of
>   template-arguments (14.3). — end note ] The top-level cv-qualifiers on the template-parameter are ignored
>   when determining its type.

Actually I didn't know about lvalue reference, I've never actually used that, nor have I used pointer to member besides pointer to member function. I have templated against `nullptr`, that is also useful at times.

Comment: You can have a `const char*` template parameter. You just can't use a string literal as an argument for such a parameter. [temp.arg.nontype]/2

Comment: thanks, I actually did not realize that. editing

Comment: This doesn't mention template template parameters.

Comment: Yakk: I read the question as asking specifically about "nontype template parameters", that's how I read the word "data type" in the question. If you want to add another answer with info about template template paramaters be my guest